Cognitive Sciences 2012-2016: Community Review
This is a first step into an attempted reboot of this community: Rebooting Cognitive Sciences: a Suggested Approach

As messy as meta is, through an organized community effort I'm hoping to collect and structure the key issues which have been plaguing this site over the years, as well as construct a backlog of past decisions which have been made in order to direct the community. Such an overview serves two purposes: (1) it creates an agenda of problems that need to be addressed and (2) it can be a stepping stone for new users to pick up were others left off, outlining why past decisions were made.
This being a scientific site, consider it a 'systematic review' of meta, albeit less rigorous. For an initial draft where this is based on, consult the following mind map which was co-constructed in chat.
This review has now been completed, and incorporates most of the key issues from the past.
Problems
Question Expertise
What constitutes a good/bad question on this site?

Assessing what is too basic relies on expertise. This community is very much divided on what is a too basic question. For example, one of our top users also struggles with making this distinction himself. Also expert users are prone to asking questions which do not suit the given format. However, we do seem to agree on what makes a good question: based on literature, assumptions made clear and backed up.
Non-technical questions can be interesting, regardless of the lack of expertise. Their answers can still teach you something new. Furthermore, they can address common misconceptions (for example on 'insanity').
Basic questions scare away experts. E.g., one of our very own mods.
Initial research should be encouraged, but deciding what is sufficient research first requires answering what is too basic. However, any research at all would already be considered an improvement.
We should mainly strive to not have invalid content on the site.
Adjust your answer to the level of initial research. When no initial research was done, the OP is likely not to understand the answer in the first place.
Without researchers, a research-level site cannot be created from the ground up.
Chasing away users we do not want might be a good thing. Putting questions on hold is one strategy to this end, which still allows them to fix it.
More important than initial research, is whether a question is answerable. SE generally speaking supports answering questions even when easily answered by a google search.
No clear decision has been made on what to do with homework questions. Should we welcome students at all?
We need to critically rethink who our target audience is. This topic has resurfaced several times now.

Self-Help Questions
Are questions explicitly or implicitly motivated by self-help concerns within the scope of our site, and what should be done about them?

Self-help questions are too localized, which goes against the Stack Exchange community guidelines.
Generally not grounded in scientific literature.
Formulating medical advise poses a liability risk.
However, one role of this site could be providing scientific answers to questions that lay people are asking in the real world.
At times these questions can be migrated to Personal Productivity or Health.
Should the answer be removed once the questions are closed?

Attracting experts
How do we attract and retain experts which are capable of answering questions, not just asking them?

Get listed on professional sites: e.g., psychology.org.
Attract psychology bloggers and research groups: e.g., a list of blogs is available here. Ask them to do a review of our site.
Post links to quality posts on other sites: e.g., some subreddits, quora, Facebook, Google+, Twitter, academic mailing lists, LinkedIn, face-to-face. A full list of these can be collected in this post. How to encourage our users in sharing links? We need to make sure to stay respectful while doing so! This is a historically effective strategy.
Top posts can be cited from Wikipedia, although this might only work in rare cases.
Promotion on academic conferences, or even making SE an integral part of a conference. There is a budget for this.
Promotion in universities, e.g., through awards, but of course, only if we in fact want to attract students.
Attracting more regular users might just be a matter of time.
Up vote posts that show research effort, down vote bad posts. Which ones are 'bad' will depend on expected question expertise. Extra efforts to introduce experts to the site (they might not be familiar to the format) are recommended.
Top questions can be shared through the official Stack Exchange social network profiles.
Do experts even have time for a site like this?
Seed the site with popular scientific topics which can attract experts.
We need to keep an eye on other Area 51 proposals to redirect them to CogSci if overlap exists. For example, a new neuroscience proposal got closed which comprised many experts, we should be welcoming to them.

Scope
Which fields of study can ask questions here? How to deal with overlap with other sites?

We decided to welcome any cognitive science, in line with the definition of Wikipedia. This includes any field which tackles the mind or its processes (behavior), including animals. E.g., Human-Computer Interaction, Neurobiology, Applied Psychology, Social Psychology, Sociology, Neuroinformatics.
This implies an overlap with sites like, e.g., Programmers, Biology, UX, Cross Validated, and Skeptics. However, when questions do not pertain to the mind or behavior, they are off topic here: e.g. some questions about HCI, statistics, coding experiments.
However, generally we do want to have a scientific focus (whether we accept laymen or not). E.g. the Autism proposal was not deemed a good fit for this site.
Concrete guidelines for overlap with specific sites is desirable: e.g., Biology, in particular neurobiology seems to repeatedly overlap.
What to do with questions about highly specific tools and tool requests is still undecided. In particular, we have many questions on neuroscience software.
There is some discussion on whether or not psychiatry should remain in scope.
Bias-laden questions are off-topic, e.g., improbably human conditions.
Our about (help section) of the site should clearly communicate what is in scope and what is not.

Site name
We have noticed our site name might lead to confusion on what this site is, what new name should we use?

The name "Cognitive Sciences" can be interpreted to only welcome cognitive science and cognitive psychology, thus excluding, e.g., non-cognitive sub-disciplines of psychology. We have collected evidence showcasing that psychology and neuroscience is often perceived to be excluded.
There is a strong majority favoring a name change.
When choosing a new name, the url prefix needs to be considered as well.
Many popular suggestions follow the format "A and B": Cognitive Science and Psychology, Psychology and Neuroscience, Mind and Brain.
An attempt at getting an overview of consensus resulted in two favorites (Psychology and Neuroscience, and Mind and Brain), with Psychology and Neuroscience as a clear winner.
Unfortunately these suggestions go against the naming standards of SE, which 'suggest' avoiding "X and B" like names.
Regardless, this is a topic which keeps resurfacing. The name keeps causing confusion even for active researchers in the fields.

Clear suggestions
Edit salvageable self-help questions

Addresses problem: Self-Help Questions

Redirect self-help questions to support groups

Addresses problem: Self-Help Questions
Put in place: Finding help with psychological and emotional problems

Promoting CogSci.SE to gain a knowledgable user-base

Addresses problem: Attracting experts
Promote users to post quality posts on other sites.
A Facebook page
Promotion on conferences.
Promotion on Stack Exchange social network.

A close reason for no initial research

Addresses problem: Question Expertise

Name with prefix: e.g., "Cognition: Psychology and Neuroscience"

Addresses problem: Site Name
Since SE does not want us to use 'and', we could agree on a singular prefix for the main name, and a more elaborate description which follows.
Music: Practice and Theory adopts a similar approach.

Allow purely technical neuroscience questions

Addresses problem: Attracting experts
A deviation from the general rule 'it has to apply to the mind' could attract these experts which currently have no place to go to.

Community decisions (i.e., should be status-completed)
Close self-help questions as off topic

Addresses problem: Self-Help Questions

A clear authoritative post to where this decision was made seems to be missing. Instead, we have some indications of this scattered throughout the site. We should probably set this up and link to it from here. I linked to the close reason for now. 
Custom off-topic self-help close message

Addresses problem: Self-Help Questions

Specify self-help questions in the FAQ

Addresses problem: Self-Help Questions

Close too broad questions, and guide them to be more specific

Addresses problem: Question Expertise
Too broad should be closed, this is in line with SE policy.


Any input on how to better structure this is welcome as well. I'm not the biggest markdown expert. Anchor hyperlinks for one, would be worthwhile.

The simplest (and therefore currently best) solution would be to have all interested users focus on the concerns that are important enough to look up for them, and post an answer. Rather than attempting to design a structure before we know what there is to structure, the OP can then be used as a place to gradually consolidate the content of those answers. Then, we distill them into decision items, and make separate questions for them, at a managed pace--maybe 1-2 decisions per month.

This is also more inclusive for people who aren't long-time Meta users/are not acutely familiar with the backlog, I think.

I guess I want to say I don't expect anything in particular, but if I did, it would be this: we need to figure out what decisions need to be made, first and foremost. What to do is secondary until that happens. Use Steven's format in your answer for topics and problems you think are important; I wouldn't write concrete recommendations or options just yet, but if you do, be explicit about what parts belong to your problem description, and what parts belong to your solution proposal. That's what I'm gonna do, at least. Iterate, iterate, iterate, then iterate some more.

Once these categories stabilize we can also assign tags to the identified questions.

In regards to, "This is also more inclusive for people who aren't long-time Meta users/are not acutely familiar with the backlog": the point is exactly to make any user familiar with the backlog (hence a review). As I said I want to "to voice the opinion of those that since might have moved on". This site is more than the currently active users, we need to respect that.

Agreed. We don't need to make extra efforts to retain users who are already active, after all. They presumably won't go away while we're improving.

What constitutes a good/bad question on this site?
(this includes 'too broad' since I believe they overlap)

What's "Too basic" or "General reference" for this site? (Jan '12)
To what extent should we allow questions asking for research about a general subject? (Jan '12)
How can we can encourage questions to show proof of initial research? (Jan '12)
What level of initial research is expected on questions? (Jan '12)
What to do with otherwise good questions that seem a bit too broad? (Jan '12)
What is the optimal scope for a question? (Jan '12)
Can questions like "Is this hypothesis correct" be answered objectively? (Jan '12)
How to deal with questions like this one on "insanity"? (Jan '12)
What kind of site do we want to be? (Mar '12)
Over-moderation and building a userbase (Mar '12)
How do I ask a good question? (Apr '12)
Should the target audience of CogSci be extended to students too? (May '12)
New users and down-voting for lack of initial research (Sep '12)
What to do with homework questions? (Sep '12)
How big is too big for questions? (Sep '13)
What should I do when my question was interesting and intriguing, to me, but the answer is too esoteric to understand? (Feb '14)
Reflection on site strategy and problem prevention (Feb '14)
Do we answer 'bad' questions here? (Apr '14)
Questions "Why are people so bad?" getting upvotes (Nov '14)
How to distinguish social psychology from opinion-based questions? (Apr '15)
Proposed Reason for Closure: No Initial Reseach (Apr '15)
What to do with expert opinion (and edge cases more generally)? (May '15)
Should we close poorly researched questions? (Sep '15)
Are we being a bit too liberal with the 'close question' function? (Sep '15)

Individual cases

Reopen request - Can an average person be involuntarily hypnotised? (Feb '12)
Can I ask here about ghost? (Jan '14)
Can you give me some advice on how to improve this question? it was classified as OT but I edited it a lot (Mar '14)
Is my question about intelligence a bad one? (Feb '16)


Answer Quality

Whether to add end of answer references as well as in text citations? (Jan '12)
Should we use the Inverted Pyramid model for answers? (Jan '12)
Do we want copy-paste answers? (Jan '12)
Should we decide on a general formatting style for references? (Feb '12)
Advice on how to write and research a good scientific answer (Feb '12)
What should an "accepted answer" mean on this site? (Feb '12)
What level of citing references or sources should be required for answers? (Feb '12)
When is it appropriate to downvote an answer? (Apr '12)
Do we want a warning about scientific answers before users answer? (Aug '12)
Is there a way to transfer a comment to an answer? (Feb '13)
How should users respond to a perceived inaccuracy in an upvoted answer? (Jul '13)
Encouraging users to accept answers (Aug '13) 
Striking a balance between citations and common sense in answers (Aug '13)
Answers posted within a minute of each other, references very similar (Aug '13)
How to deal with questions that have a perfect answer on Wikipedia? (Sep '13)
What should I do when my question was interesting and intriguing, to me, but the answer is too esoteric to understand? (Feb '14)
Answers that are personal experience: discouraged? How? (Sep '14)
Are cognitive sciences actually being... scientific? (Nov '14)
Should we remove answers to self-help questions? (Dec '14)
"Flag" and "Recommend Deletion" options for answers that are merely unscientific opinions (Jul '15)
How to deal with personal answers? (Apr '16)
Should mods be able to accept an answer? (Jun '16)
Feedback of "not an answer but a comment" flag (Nov '16)


Is this list complete, or an ad-hoc selection of a few related posts?

Ad-hoc. Just figured it may deserve it's own topic, because I couldn't place artem's and my question and I saw some more answer-focused questions. I'll make it more complete this evening.

Attracting experts (site-promotion?)

How can we promote the site and reach out to industry experts? (Jan '12)
Where else are people asking scientific questions about psychology and cognitive science? (Jan '12)
How to engage with graduate students and academics in psychology and cognitive science? (Feb '12)
How to include cogsci.se as an accompanying Q&A site for a conference? (Feb '12)
How can we encourage existing users of cogsci.se to announce the site on Google+? (Feb '12)
What popular online communities exist that permit sharing links and are relevant to cogsci.se? (Feb '12)
How to respectfully engage with online communities? (Feb '12)
Are there any email discussion lists popular in cognitive science or psychology? (Feb '12)
What are cost effective strategies for site promotion at an academic conference? (Feb '12)
Promoting the site to psychology and cognitive science majors at university? (Feb '12)
How can we promote the site on LinkedIn? (Feb '12)
How can we increase the number of 'regulars' on the site? (Mar '12)
How can we get our site reviewed by relevant bloggers? (May '12)
Help promote the site via the offical Stack Exchange social network profiles! (May '12)
Keeping up with the Joneses (or Bio.SEs) (Aug '12)
Suggest site promotion ideas (Sep '12)
Why is the Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange community so small? What we can do about it? (Oct '12)
Site promotion strategies revisited March 2013 (Mar '13)
Raising awareness of CogSci's success on other Area 51 sites (Aug '13)
Which settings should we choose for the posts to the cogsci.SE Facebook page? (Feb '14)
A new CogSci.SE Facebook page (Jul '16)
We should be more welcoming to technical Neuroscience questions (Aug '16)
At what time of day is the best moment to promote the website? (Aug '16) 
Actively engaging psychology departments on Facebook? (Oct '16)


I do not recall whether the following has been discussed before, but one thing I started doing is being much more open to new users who give indications of possibly being experts (e.g. only an account at CogSci, no other networks). The last thing we want to do is scare them off just because they might not be familiar with the network. Personal guidance here could be key in retaining them. (Not to say you should not always do this, but it is worthwhile considering next time you leave a comment which could be interpreted as hostile by someone not familiar with the network.)

What is the scope of our site? Which topics are welcome?
(excluding the topic self-help, as that is an obvious sub-topic which we acted on)

Are questions about Human Computer Interaction (HCI) research on or off topic? (Jan '12)
What is our site NOT about? (Jan '12)
Are questions about animals on topic? (Jan '12)
Are questions about neurobiology on or off topic? (Jan '12)
Are questions on applied fields of psychology allowed? (Jan '12)
Splitting up questions on neurobiology between cognitivesciences.se and biology.se? (Feb '12)
What to do with questions related to statistical analysis of psychological variables? (Feb '12)
Are "tool request" questions acceptable? Should we have guidelines for them? (Apr '12)
Is Sociology on topic? (Apr '12)
Neuroinformatics and cognitive sciences? (Apr '12)
Autism Area 51 Proposal (Jun '12)
Neurobiology Rivalries, part IV, A New Hope? (Jul '12)
Tag for "Human Factors" and related issues (Sep '12)
Are questions about coding psychology and cognitive science experiments, simulations, etc. on topic? (Nov '12)
What should we list in the "Ask about..." / "Don't ask about..." section of /about? (Mar '13)
Can we drop Psychiatry? (Aug '13)
Is social psychology on-topic? (Aug '13)
Are questions involving improbable human conditions on topic? (Oct '13)
Are specific brain facts about specific people considered on topic? (Aug '14)
Neurobiology Rivalries, part V, A Newer Hope? (March '15)
Repeated, specific questions on comp neurosci software (Jul '15)
We should be more welcoming to technical Neuroscience questions (Aug '16)
Sociology questions (Sep '16)
Methodology is Hard, Let's Go Shopping! (Oct '16)
Are events from the newspapers with a hint of CogSci on-topic? (Nov '16)

Individual cases

Can I ask here about ghost? (Jan '14)


Are dogs and other animals, within our scope?

@RobinKramer Yes, the previous consensus seemed to be that it should be. In fact, it is already listed in the incomplete list of this post. However, I feel scope should also be renegotiated, but this is less important than the 'expertise' discussion for now.

Ah excuse me. I missed that one.

Self-help questions

What is our site NOT about? (Jan '12)
Do we want a disclaimer on the sidebar that we cannot offer medical advice? (Mar '12)
Do we need a self-help question policy? (Apr '12)
Why was my self-help question closed as off-topic? (Dec '12)
Our FAQ endorses self-help questions (Dec '12)
What should our custom "Off Topic" close reasons be? (Jun '13)
General strategies for converting self-help into a useful general question for this site (Jul '13)
Link list for self-help questions? (Nov '13)
Finding help with psychological and emotional problems (Feb '14)
Should we remove answers to self-help questions? (Dec '14)
What exactly is a self-help question? (Feb '15)
With self-help questions, close or edit? (Jul '15)
Should we adjust the 'self-help' close message? (Apr '15)
"I have X, how common is X?": self help question, or not? (Aug '15)
Self-help questions (on Health SE) (Aug '15)

Individual cases

Deleted question? (Aug '13)
Question put on hold as self help question when it isn't - how to improve? (Apr '14)
How does a near decade of non-treatment affect what a doctor prescribes? - Deleted question (Aug '15)
How to deal with personal answers? (Apr '16)


Since the decision was already made to close self-help questions, we can start compiling a single authoritative Community Wiki question/answer. This can then be much more easily maintained and communicated going forward.

@ChristianHummeluhr I believe Why was my self-help question closed as off-topic? is what you are looking for. Quite certain it is also linked to from the close reason, and it is tagged [meta-tag:faq]. Self-help questions were one of the early decisions we made as there was a big enough community to decide on this and the opinion of closing them was quite unanimous given the possible consequences of not doing so.

Here's my current complaint about how the self-help close message is applied. There are cases where a person posts a question amounting to something like "I did X. I'm curious about X." This almost always gets at least a few close votes if not actually closed because the person includes some kind of personal anecdote. My opinion is that we should close under this banner when the answer would be localized to the individual. But if the question has an anecdote to motivate it, that's fine with me. It probably even makes the question a bit more understandable.

@Josh Could you post/track examples of this? I would agree that is fine, but I thought it is mostly applied when a question is quite clearly inspired by getting help, i.e., guidance on what to do. E.g., this is not closed as self-help.

I voted to leave this open, for example: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13002/is-there-a-disorder-that-causes-one-to-feel-heat-from-an-inanimate-object

@Josh I closed it because of this "She's becoming very anxious over this". This to me gives the impression they are after a diagnosis in order to provide help/information/prescription. It is an interesting example though, and would definitely be useful to bring up during a discussion in the future when we revisit this issue.

It's clearly about an individual, and it's right on the border of what I would consider acceptable. Looking back, maybe it's more appropriate to close. But if there was another question that said "I've noticed that my friend Joe always wants to continue working on projects that he's put a lot of time into but seem to be doomed to fail. Is there any cognitive disorder that could explain this?" then I don't think we would should close because a general answer about the sunk-cost fallacy would be appropriate to describing behavior like Joe's.

Yeah, I agree that the question I used as an example seems to be looking for a diagnosis and that makes it more of a problem.

New site name

How will branding affect the perceived inclusiveness of cognitive science and psychology? (Jan '12)
Whither a more inclusive site name? (Apr '12)
What do people think of "Cognitive Science and Psychology" as a site title? (Apr '12)
"Mind and Brain (Sciences)" as a site title (May '12)
Evidence of name confusion (Jul '12)
Should we change the site name to Mind? (Mar '13)
What should we change the name of our site to, if anything? (Mar '13)
Why is this stack exchange called 'Cognitive Sciences'? (Jul '15)
Vote for a new site name! (Aug '15)


This is the least of our problems. Enough people find the website and usually post relevant questions. Let us worry about this after having decided on the scope.

@RobinKramer The purpose of this overview is to list recurring problems over the past four years. ;p This has been a major problem in the past as will become clear if you read through the different posts, all on the same subject. However, I fully agree scope is more important, it could even influence the name in case it changes drastically. Both, however, should be on the agenda.

When I have time I will distill the key problem points and add them to the main post to clarify what the exact problem is (as we should do with all listed issues).

Absolutely true, I just wanted it to be last on the list, which explains my down vote ;) I do think we should start discussing the key problem points soon so we cán put it in the main post. (I already started on my own in the chat )

Although I'm also working on the other issues, @StevenJeuris what is the state of this? Was the original vote for "Psychology and Neuroscience" seemed to have majority vote, but then you left the suggestion to switch it to "Cognition" in the chat for some reason?

@Seanny123 We requested a change but given both (1) the 'and' in the title (or '&'), and (2) a seemingly indecisive (too small) community, the community team didn't act on it. A bigger community is hopefully addressed by the suggested approach. My suggestion to resolve the ampersand issue was to use: Cognition: Psychology and Neuroscience.
